# Fish Eye effect on a JLabel

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, hover, jlabel

I am trying to implement a [Fish Eye Image Menu](http://www.google.com/search?q=Fish%20Eye%20Image%20Menu&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X) in a [JavaBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/). As a start, I created a `JLabel` and put this code on the `mouseEntered` event. But when I run this, the output is shaky and doesn't re-size the `JLabel`.

This is my code.

```
new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i &lt; 30; i++) {
      int x = imgLabel.getWidth()+1;
      int y = imgLabel.getHeight()+1;
      imgLabel.setSize(x , y );

      // sets the icon to the label
      imgLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pics/icon.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(x , y, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
      repaint();
      try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}.start();
```

If I comment that line where I set the image to the JLabel, the label gets re-sized perfectly.
Where has this gone wrong?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - I would be more surprised if that mess of code lines worked, than failed.  1) [Don't call setSize(..)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) 2) Do GUI updates on the EDT.  3) Don't sleep on the EDT.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: I know it's a messy code as I couldn't think of another way. Anyhow, thanks a lot for the comment and the links you provided. It was a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that getScaledInstance() together with resource loading is slow. Do these calculations once and cache them (in an array of 30 items). Not every time in the for loop.

Another thing: make sure you use a Swingworker for your animation, that helps in the timing and avoids setting icons outside the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments. And I think I have to learn more on these stuff.
@bluevoid : Thanks for the TIP. I'll try that.

Comment: Even if I use SwingWorker, I have to re-size the image.So is there any way to do this then? I mean, to re-size the image as an animation.

Comment: "Do these calculations once and cache them (in an array of 30 items)" do this on startup